# golang breakpoints not work in intellij idea 2016.1.1

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, go

I was debugging a GoLang program. I set break points and run the debugger. But the break points only works the first time I run the debugger and failed in the second, the third, and all following debugging whatever I do. I cancelled them and reset them, I close the debugging window and open a new one, I change the settings in the "Breakpoints" tool window. All these didn't work at all.
What's the problem?

Comment: make sure run to the breakpoints by adding log firstly.

Comment: @JiangYD What kind of log should be added firstly?

Comment: any print to stdout, to make sure the breakpoint is reached.

Answer (score 3):

Update, this has been fixed in the latest release of the plugin, please [check it out](http://go-ide.com/releases/0.11.1725/)

This is a well known problem and it lies in delve not the plugin itself. Please see this [this issue](https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin/issues/2360) for further reference.